# grunt watch: how to run specific jasmine spec file on change in source code

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jasmine, grunt-contrib-watch

I can configure grunt watch to run all spec files when any of the app files was changed.

```
 watch: {
            files: [ app_files, test_files],
            tasks: ['jasmine']
}

jasmine : {
            src : [...],
            options : {
                specs : ['specs/*.js'],
                vendor: [...]
            }
        }
```

How can grunt be configured so that a change in x.js will run x-spec.js and not more, so that the errors can be isolated?

Comment: It sounds like an unusual situation to have tests failing in many files at the same time. Is this a frequent problem in your project?

Comment: Not yet. I think just that this is more correct.

Comment: In practice you are really only changing one file at at time. The 'watch' task only becomes useful once your tests are already passing. You get alerted when you have just broken something. You will already know which file it was that broke your tests, won't you?